# where can I find the missing comments in my wordpress dashboard?

Tags: comments, admin, dashboard

When I log into my wordpress dashboard, it states that there are 937 comments, but when I click on the approved link to view them, there are a only 3 comments that I can view. How can I find those other comments, and why aren't they showing up?
[image: When I log into the backend]
[image: When I click the link]

Comment: do you see the same 3 comments if you click on "Approved" ?

Comment: Yes, but the other 934 don't show anywhere in the system

Comment: There are 965 now